# Not Getting Row From Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using `mysqli` to get the row but it is not giving me row, and there is no error in query.

```
$query="select * from members where useremail='$user_email' and password='$password'";
$result=$db->query($query);
$row = $db->fetch_array($result);
echo $row['id'];
```

My `query` Function

```
function query($query){
        $result=mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
        if(!$result){
            echo $this->err_msg = mysqli_error($this->conn);
            return false;
        }else{
            return $result;
        }
}
```

My `fetch_array` Function

```
function fetch_array($result){
    return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}
```

How can i get Row using `mysqli` ?

Comment: Your code is likely vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: @AlexHowansky i am using mysqli.

Comment: Yes but you're not using prepared statements with bound parameters.

Comment: @Hamza Tafeer That doesnt mean that you can't build SQL injections. You don't use the common way from mysqli to prevent it.

Comment: @Stony ok, but now how can i get row?

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Change your original code to reflect bound parameters using mysqli, this is more secure and should work

```
$query="select * from members where useremail='$user_email' and password='$password'";
    $result=$db->query($query);
    $row = $db->fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['id'];
```

to bound parameters using mysqli prepared statements

```
$query="select id from members where useremail=? and password=?";   // Don't use select *, select each column, ? are placeholders for your bind variables
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
if($stmt){
  $stmt->bind_param("ss",$user_email,$password);   // Bind in your variables, s is for string, i is for integers
  $stmt->execute();  
  $stmt->bind_result($id);  // bind the result to these variables, in the order you select
  $stmt->store_result();   // Store if large result set, can throw error if server is setup to not handle more than x data
  $stmt->fetch();
  $stmt->close();
  }
echo $id;  // this would be same as $row['id'], $id now holds for example 5.
```

If you select multiple things, such as `"SELECT id,name FROM..."`, then when you bind_result(..), just bind them n there. `$stmt->bind_result($id,$name);`

now $id and $name hold the column data for that row matching your query.  If there would be multiple rows matching, instead of $stmt->fetch() you'd do

```
while($stmt->fetch()){    // just like while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){}
   echo $id;
   echo $name
}
```

Comment: how can i get `$row['id']` and i want to store it in session, i am using mysqli not using prepared statement?  I means i want a complete row and then get any thing from row?

Comment: You would do `"SELECT id..."`,  then bind_result($id).   $row['id'] would now be $id.     And yes you're using mysqli, prepared statements are an idea to prevent SQL injection attacks. Each iteration of the while($stmt->fetch()) provides you with the same result as if you were to do while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()).  The $row['id'] would now be accessed using $id;